# I don't understand the -(CGAffineTransform) nodeToParentTransform on Cocos2D+Box2D example

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, geometry, box2d

I write this question because I don't understand a piece of code in an example provided by Cocos2D for iPhone:

```
-(CGAffineTransform) nodeToParentTransform
{   
b2Vec2 pos  = body_->GetPosition();

float x = pos.x * PTM_RATIO;
float y = pos.y * PTM_RATIO;

if ( ignoreAnchorPointForPosition_ ) {
    x += anchorPointInPoints_.x;
    y += anchorPointInPoints_.y;
}

// Make matrix
float radians = body_->GetAngle();
float c = cosf(radians);
float s = sinf(radians);

if( ! CGPointEqualToPoint(anchorPointInPoints_, CGPointZero) ){
    x += c*-anchorPointInPoints_.x + -s*-anchorPointInPoints_.y;
    y += s*-anchorPointInPoints_.x + c*-anchorPointInPoints_.y;
}

// Rot, Translate Matrix
transform_ = CGAffineTransformMake( c,  s,
                                   -s,  c,
                                   x,   y );    

return transform_;
}
```

It's in the PhysicsSprite.mm file.

Maybe it's because *I'm very bad* with space geometry, but if someone can explain me, I very appreciate.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( ! CGPointEqualToPoint(anchorPointInPoints_, CGPointZero) ){
    x += c*-anchorPointInPoints_.x + -s*-anchorPointInPoints_.y;
    y += s*-anchorPointInPoints_.x + c*-anchorPointInPoints_.y;
}
```

The above piece of code simply rotates the xy coordinate axes anticlockwise by $180-\theta$
degrees, and adds the new coordinates to the previous x,y coordinates that were obtained from  the piece of code before the above mentioned lines.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes provides the rotation of axes formula

Comment: Yes, ok, but why ? ... If I completely remove this piece of code, the object in my scene don't move with the gravity and I don't understand why ...